# Is it possible to use the NPM repository to distribute Nodejs programs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am not an experienced user either of Nodejs or NPM. From what I have read until now, I suppose the NPM registry to be an effective tool to distribute NodeJS projects as libraries to be used as dependencies in further Nodejs projects: the `npm install`  command, indeed, requires some Nodejs project as destination for the installation.

My question is: is it possible to use the NPM repository to distribute Nodejs programs too? By 'program' I mean a Nodejs project with an executable '`main`' script. Does the NPM CLI allow the user to install anywhere in his disk and run such a program? If not, how to distribute a Nodejs program?

Comment: It is possible. Lots of cli tools used in nodejs development are published in the npm registry. Npm itself was published in the registry. REF: https://hackernoon.com/publishing-a-nodejs-cli-tool-to-npm-in-less-than-15-minutes

Comment: @seenukarthi  If I well understand `npx` is designed to run Nodejs projects from the NPM repository as programs. Thank you very much!